# Client distribution of an iPhone App via AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store, client, distribution

I work for a start up company and have just developed a paid iPhone app for a client who is not in anyway tech-savvy. She knows very little about the appstore process and does not have a developer account or even a mac.

What we basically need to know is what is the standard way of distributing an app from the clients side?
Does a separate developer account need to be created by the client and the app signed with their certificates? Or...

Can we release it under our own developer license using their bank details in the paid app contract? If so are multiple paid app contracts allowed so that we can release more paid apps for other clients or ourselves?

I have looked around SO and haven't been able to find an answer applicable to our case. Most scenarios inolved the client already owning a developer license.

Comment: Try asking in the Apple Dev Forum. There are many related posts there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one paid app contract per developer enrollment is allowed.  If you want to work with multiple clients (or have your own apps in the App store), each client will need their own ADC account and iOS developer enrollment.

If they can't enroll by themselves, you might have them loan you an email account in their domain to use for their ADC account, use of their company credit card for the $99, legally authorize you (in writing) to apply, click agree, and enter their banking and tax info.  Or sit down with them with your Mac and tell them which boxes to click, and which private info to fill in, line by line.  If they are a corporation, have them ready to fax incorporation (etc.) papers to Apple.  If they have a legal department, you may need to give them a copy of all Apple's agreements ahead of time to review.

Then, after they are enrolled, you can use their ADC account login, from a separate User account on your Mac so as not to contaminate your keychain, to get certificates, build, sign and submit their app for them.

If they want to keep their financial information private, they can always change the password on their ADC team leader account after letting you submit their app.

Comment: Thanks, I was kind of hoping there was another way around but live and learn. Should've realised this earlier.

Comment: Would using the same User account really "contaminate" the keychain?

Comment: Keychain problems with multiple Developer certificates have been reported by developers in the past.  Why take chances?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the profits from app purchases to be given to your client directly, they must have their own account. Otherwise, you can set them up as a user on your account so that they are able to monitor sales and then you send them the procedes afterwards. However in your case it sounds like they would like the money directly.

Buy a new account, set up the distribution certificates and keypairs on a separate computer than the one with all your dev keys for your current account, or even a seperate account on the same computer; keychains do not overlap between users. Sign the package, upload (wait a week) and viola. Give them the credentials to the new developer account and watch the money roll in.

Comment: You don't need a separate computer, just a separate User account on your Mac.